# CSS File is not loading in my CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload, base-url

I am new in Codeigniter. I tried to load my css file but i failed. I search it google apply all solution but its not working.

I also made changes in mu `autoload` file

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

**Here is my Controller code with name Login.php**

```
<?php
    class Login extends CI_Controller{
        function index(){
            $this->load->helper('url'); 
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
            $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

**And Here is My View Code Name with login_form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="login_form">
        <h1>Login Page..!!</h1>
        <?php
        echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
        echo form_input('username', 'Username');
        echo form_password('password', 'Password');
        echo form_submit ('submit', 'Login');
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Folder Structure

```
Config
controller
css
helper
models
views
```

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors.. and tell us the errors.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal how i can do that?

Comment: right click on the page and click inspect

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal it shows 404 error but my file path is correct then wht it show me 404 error?

Comment: Can you please share the exact URL which gives the 404?

Comment: Make sure your `base_url();` include `/` at end

Comment: I think path is wrong use this `<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url();?>/css/style.css">`

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal Thanks Buddy i found my error. actually i place my css folder in application folder and its need to place outside the application folder :) :) Thanks allot Man

Comment: take the source of the html and verify the css path

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal please add your comment as an answer i want to approve your answer thank you

Comment: @sunny sure i will

Comment: @sunny i have added the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your browser console by right clicking on your web page and select inspect.

Go to your network requests / console and check what URL you get for your linked files (CSS).

If you find out that the path you have given in your application if different then you need to change your code accordingly to get the appropriate path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `base_url()` is the root of your domain (e.g. `http://localhost`), then it will return the root directory of the application (the directory where CodeIgniter's `index.php` is stored). So all you have to do is move your `css` folder up to that directory. I believe it's one step up from the current location of your `css` folder.

Please also take note that you have to set the base_url() in your CodeIgniter `config.php` file, like so:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url();?>application/css/style.css">
```

CI's default webroot is out of application folder which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**solved your issue move your css folder out of application folder and place on root structure will be**

```
->application
->css
```

Answer (score 0):

First maintains your folder structure download cod igniter and start with new structure

Set base url in config file if you can use CI-version 3

Set with your project folder name

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_folder_name';

And load css using base_url() :generally we are use bae_url() for load js,css,images

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
```